Automating (activate Python virtualenv) with visual studio task does not work
I have a .env in workspace VSCODE with the following code:
echo "The .env file was triggered."
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon app_3.12_virt_env

when I execute this file with source .env
the virtualenv is activated
When I create a tasks.json inside the .vscode with the following code:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Activate Virtual Environment",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "source .env",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
}

The task is not triggered on startup
If I use command palette and run the task the terminal displays :
 *  Executing task in folder xrx_app: source .env 

The .env file was triggered.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

But nothing happened, why there is no execution?
Is there an error in tasks.json?
I already set -> manage tasks -> allow automatic tasks
Linux ZorinOS 17

VSCODE Version: 1.89.0
Commit: b58957e67ee1e712cebf466b995adf4c5307b2bd
Date: 2024-05-01T02:08:25.066Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.0-28-generic


Visual studio setting for tasks
I tried to add the paramater auto true as per question:
VSCODE: How do i enable "tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks In Folder" by default?
It did not work same if I use the extension mentioned in the question.
I also tried with all the extensions disable
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211851#issue-2275941603
The task is now triggered on startup with the extension after I change the setting to Auto
But the script or the command does not execute, it is only showing up in the terminal windows.
I changed the config of the tasks as well and tried different parameters:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Activate Virtual Environment",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/virtualenv.sh",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": false
            }
        }
    ]
}

